# Reload tableview without scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, swift5

I am new to swift
I want to reload my tableview so I used tableviewName.reloadData()
After this the table view is reloaded and scrolled a bit upwards but I want to stay where it is

Here is the code

func searchResult(row: Int, searchText: String, tag: Int) {

(defaultAnswerQuestionsArray[tag] as! DefaultAnswerObjectClass).defaultAnswerId = row

```
    (defaultAnswerQuestionsArray[tag] as! DefaultAnswerObjectClass).defaultAnswerDescription = searchText
    tableViewCollection.reloadData()
    tableViewCollection.alwaysBounceVertical = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reload just visible cells like this:

```
let indexPaths = tableView.visibleCells.map { tableView.indexPath(for: $0) }.compactMap { $0 }
tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the content offset of the table-view using `setContentOffset` after reload.

```
func searchResult(row: Int, searchText: String, tag: Int) {

(defaultAnswerQuestionsArray[tag] as! DefaultAnswerObjectClass).defaultAnswerId = row

    (defaultAnswerQuestionsArray[tag] as! DefaultAnswerObjectClass).defaultAnswerDescription = searchText
    tableViewCollection.reloadData()
    tableViewCollection.alwaysBounceVertical = false
     
    /* NEW */
    let contentOffset = tableViewCollection.contentOffset
    tableViewCollection.layoutIfNeeded() 
    tableViewCollection.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
}
```